# Changing a MySQL Table Structure JSON

Tags: mysql

I need some help. I created a database. Using the same database I  installed how can I add a JSON field named “customers_contacts” to the customers table with the following keys: customerNumber and contactLastName etc
 Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you Googled "ALTER TABLE"?

Comment: Thanks Sloan for the hint, I thought about it but I was not sure since most examples started with CREATE. I will check that and try it. I appreciate the hint.

Comment: I figured out my IDE was not compatible with JSON that's why it failed. Thank you.